# If $f$ is bijective, then $f^{- 1}$ is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> If $f$ is bijective, then $f^{- 1}$ is bijective.

*My attempt:* If $f$ is bijective, then $f$ has an inverse which is $f^{- 1}$, but $f^{- 1}$ also has an inverse which is $f$, so $f^{- 1}$ is bijective since it has an inverse. But how to prove that $f^{- 1}$ is bijective?

Comment: What are a bijetora and a bijector?

Comment: You could check that the function has an inverse iff it's a bijection. (PS: salve, camarada)

Comment: You will find it easier to make this argument if you introduce notation for the domain and range of $f$.  I think the English word you want here is the adjective "bijective", meaning one-to-one and onto as a function (mapping of sets).  Bijector is okay English, more used by programmers, and a more common noun is "bijection".

Answer (score 2):

A function $h: A \to B$ is bijective if and only if there is a function $g: B \to A$ such that $g \circ h =1_A$ and $h \circ g = 1_B$.

Now, apply this with $h= f^{-1}$ and $g=f$ to conclude that $f^{-1}$ is bijective.

Comment: What did you mean by that here: "apply this with $h = f^{ - 1}$ and $g = f$ "?
to conclude that $f^{ - 1}$ is bijective.

Comment: If $f: B \to A$ is a function, then $f\circ f^{-1}= 1_A$ and $f^{-1} \circ f = 1_B$ by definition of inverse. Hence, by my claim we must have that $f^{-1}$ is bijective.

Comment: HM thanks for the help !!!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Here in this group, how to mark the participants in the posts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you try to rephrase? What do you mean with participants in this posts?

Comment: Like, tag a person in the question for them to see. Is that to study analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and wanted to know if my questions are right. You were very polite to me, the rest is not like that. Do you only participate in this group here?

Comment: If you want you can write a comment under this answer to notify me if you have other questions.

Comment: It may be, wow I don't even know how to thank you. I'll post later.

Comment: A good way to say thank you is to accept this answer. Near the "upvote-downvote" buttons you should find another button which lets you accept an answer. This way, other users know your question is solved and it gains you some small reputation as well. Have a great day/night!

Comment: Where is this button to open? I can open it.

Comment: @FernandaDuarte It is a little hard to explain. There should be a button next to my answer. Here is more information I found: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

A function is injective if and only if it has an inverse if and only if bijective onto its image.